# Request Parameters from url through iframe with Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpagesurl

I have a landing page lead form created in Salesforce Marketing cloud which we're hosting on our Wordpress website via iframe.

Within the lead form we are pushing all new leads to individual campaigns depending on the campaign id which we would like to be dynamic within the URL `"www.example.com/?cid=123campaignid"`. The issue is that because the marketing cloud url for the lead form is added to the iframe and then the url to the page is our website url I cannot figure out how to pull the campaign ID from the website url.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use Javascript to pass the parameter to your iframe:

```
var loc = window.location.toString(),
    params = loc.split('?')[1],
    iframe = document.getElementById('myIframe');

iframe.src = iframe.src + '?' + params;​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```